# Is there a way to open a VS08 solution in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

We have some older projects in VS 2008 format and the newer ones in VS2010. Its reshource hogging to have both open. I am wondering if there is a way to make VS2010 open VS2008 solutions without converting any project/solution files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmya, don't look for a complicated solution when the obvious one is simple.  Just copy your solution and project files and give them a distinctive name.  Postfix "10", anything goes.  And open them in VS2010 to get them converted.  Run a diff on the source code files, just in case, there shouldn't be any.  Check them in.  You can now open the original in VS2008 and the converted in VS2010.

Comment: If it was a smaller solution it wouldve been easy

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you can target the varying platforms (2, 3.5, etc...) but once it is converted from a VS stance, it is converted.